# What's the antonym of "serendipitous"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

What's the antonym of "serendipitous"? I couldn't find any anywhere.

Comment: ...Unfortunate?

Comment: First, look for the synonyms of "serendipitous", then for antonyms of the results.

Comment: Weird, http://thesaurus.com/browse/serendipitous?s=t lists all manner of antonyms (which apply to the other definition of "beneficial, favorable", as well).

Comment: It depends on which part of the term you want to oppose - the accidental or the beneficial aspects.

Comment: Spot on, bib. 'Serendipitous' is a word whose meaning involves both the aspects you mention, and as this is, off the top of my head, quite unusual, excepting compound words, it is unlikely that a word carrying both opposite aspects exists. This property is not polysemy, where one word is used with different but related senses in different contexts - it is a word carrying different aspects in a single context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Unlucky" is almost an antonym, although serendipitous is more specific than just "lucky" and refers to finding good things by accident. "Ill-fated," "luckless" or "star-crossed" might work.

Comment: Did you mean antonym instead of acronym?

Comment: What does "star-crossed" mean?

Comment: Cursed, fated for bad things. Like Romeo and Juliet being described as "star-crossed lovers"

Comment: "Star-crossed" doesn't mean fated for bad things in that context; it simply means blocked or thwarted by bad luck.

Comment: @Robusto: I don't see a distinction there. Obviously *star-crossed*  comes from the astrological reference (as in *born under a bad sign*, etc.), so "fated for bad things" seems a perfectly accurate paraphrasing to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's mainly a literary distinction I'm trying to draw here. There is a school of thought which holds that Shakespearean tragedy is heavily influenced by the hallmarks of Greek drama, including *that* sort of fate. I don't believe there is an inexorable fate that drew Romeo and Juliet to their doom based on hubris and hamartia, etc. Now, make the argument about Hamlet and I might be convinced. ^_^

Comment: @Robusto: oic. You mean if we take Romeo and Juliet as the "definitive" exemplar of *star-crossed*, it's got more a sense of "shit happens", rather than the [deserved? inevitable?] bad things that happened to/around Oedipus & Electra, for example?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: More or less, yes.

Comment: Robusto, thanks for adding that distinction; I found this side discussion really interesting.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia offers "zemblanity" as an antonym:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serendipity

Makes sense, but it doesn't roll as pleasantly off the tongue as "serendipity" does; then again, it's not nearly as pleasant an experience.

Comment: Your answer is slightly misleading, almost suggesting that the term is recognized. It isn't, not yet in any case. Please edit your post and include the relevant citation: *"William Boyd coined the term zemblanity to mean somewhat the opposite of serendipity: "making unhappy, unlucky and expected discoveries occurring by design"*

Answer (score -1):

Serendipitous doesn't have a "proper" antonym is because a word that was invented/created in 1754 ([per wikipedia - credit to user96494). It was coined by Horace Walpole in a letter.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serendipity) , so it has no etymology and therefor no real antonym. This is also why it is so hard to translate into other languages.