# I need a word for things not going your way

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for things not happening the way someone would want it to. For example, if you're at the ice cream parlor buying some icecream but they don't have vanilla, your favorite flavor, you would have to buy chocolate. Generic example aside, *is* there even a word for life not going your way? (One-two word answer, not a phrase)

Comment: That would be such a **drag**.

Comment: Depending on the context, "sh*t happens" might do.

Comment: Maybe [bummer!](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bummer)

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80086/131620 which discusses antoymns for serendipity which may help. Unfortunately no neat answer at that page.

Comment: As [Drake](http://genius.com/1563732/Drake-successful/Yeah-i-want-things-to-go-my-way-but-as-of-late-a-lot-of-shit-been-going-sideways) raps it: "Yeah, I want things to go my way. But as of late, a lot of shit been **going sideways**."

Comment: For many people the term is "normal".

Comment: Just my luck - my answer is one word too long.

Comment: Side note - "everything's coming up nettles" netted exactly one hit used precisely this way. "But not everything at this time is coming up nettles! I bear a strong belief in the improvement of the future!". https://books.google.com/books?id=UrjW8NN-XfUC&lpg=PA136&ots=MeX3pzLst8&dq=%22coming%20up%20nettles%22&pg=PA136#v=onepage&q=%22coming%20up%20nettles%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

You can probably call them ***[mishaps](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mishap)***:

> - an unpredictable outcome that is unfortunate.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with being slightly crude, try:

> [Some days you're the dog, other days you're the hydrant.](http://www.metaphordogs.org/Dogs/entries/sometime.html)

This idiom follows from the fact that dogs very stereotypically urinate upon fire hydrants while out for a walk, supposedly as a way of marking territory.  When you are the dog, you are the one doing the marking, you are in charge, on top of the world.  When you are the hydrant, well, you are the one getting marked.

Comment: Although this seems to convey the meaning, I think OP wants very short phrases.

Answer (score 1):

**letdown** (n.)

> A disappointment:
>
> *After all I'd heard about the movie, it turned out to be somewhat of a **letdown***.
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/letdown)

> Disillusionment, discouragement, or disappointment:
>
> *The job was a **letdown***.
> [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/letdown)

---

> Talk about failure. That was the biggest **letdown** of my entire
> life! I had let down my entire family, not to mention myself.
> Suddenly, my hopes and dreams were dashed—all because I made on
> idiotic mistake by trusting a common thief disguised in a sharp
> designer suit.
> [Mathew Knowles; *The DNA of Achievers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8qO5CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT136&dq=biggest%20letdown%20in%20my%20life&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfkoDEw8yDAxX4FVkFHWbmASgQ6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=biggest%20letdown%20in%20my%20life&f=false) (2015)

> I rarely order chocolate ice cream because it's so often a
> **letdown**, tasting more like sugar than actual chocolate. Not this one!
> [Christie Matheson; *Salty Sweets*](https://www.google.com/search?q=ice%20cream%20flavor%20letdown&sca_esv=596428686&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKmmmTGwkSKkHp5ZfpuboWZZjpQcqA:1704673654975&ei=dkGbZbiLO9-hiLMPvMivsAs&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi4nqadxMyDAxXfEGIAHTzkC7YQ8NMDegQIAhAW&biw=1250&bih=645&dpr=1.09) (2010)

Answer (score 0):

a **haphazard** life  [TFD](https://www.freethesaurus.com/haphazard)

> characterized by lack of order or planning; irregular; chance;
>   random.

Answer (score 0):

You imply that getting the chocolate ice cream isn't actually a disaster, despite its not being your first choice.

So maybe you'll accept your ***second choice***. A pithier way of saying this is

### Plan B

which, [according to dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plan-b), is

> a strategy or plan to be implemented if the original one proves impracticable or unsuccessful.

The use of "Plan B"(R) as a brand of "morning-after" contraceptive rather underscores its suitability for the meaning you wanted.

Of course, there's always the possibility that you'll have to come up with a Plan C, D, etc......

Answer (score 0):

“Unlucky.”  As in, “I am an unlucky person.”

“Misfortune.”  As in, “I have had a lot of misfortune in my life.”

“Jinxed.”  As in, “Every time I think something will finally go my way, it doesn’t.  I think I am jinxed.”

“Cursed.”  Same use as jinxed.

See if one of those work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I would call it 'disappointed', or 'disappointment'.

As in you felt disappointed when they were unable to fulfill your desire, expectation, or request.

Ref: online Dictionary for the word, 'Disappointed', definition & meaning.   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disappointed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I think that it would be a *fail.* This is a word for things failing to go your way. Your scenario could be, "I went to get some ice cream, but they *failed* to have my favorite flavor, vanilla." Just a suggestion! :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please link to and quote from a resource that supports your answer.

Answer (score -1):

SNAFU which stands for: "Situation Normal All Fk'd Up" SNAFU was a flag we used to fly on our ship during the Vietnam War -- our unofficial motto was: The schedule has been changed, because we were always giving up scheduled periods of R & R in exchange for Search and Rescue missions.

Comment: BTW, for most in the military, R & R stands for Rest & Relaxation, but for us it normally stood for Repair & Replenishment, although we also enjoyed our Liberty Calls in numerous ports as well.